# How do I avoid this case of Late Binding when connecting multiple button signals in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to connect multiple buttons to the same method but each with a different argument to that method. In this case the argument is the index of the button in a list of all buttons.

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        #We declare each button
        self.pushButton_01 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_02 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_03 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_04 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_05 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_06 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        #We combine the buttons in a list
        list_of_buttons = [self.pushButton_01,self.pushButton_02,self.pushButton_03,self.pushButton_04,self.pushButton_05,self.pushButton_06]
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        #We add each button to the layout
        for button in list_of_buttons:
            layout.addWidget(button)
        #This is supposed to connect each button in a way that in prints out its index in the list above
        for button in list_of_buttons:
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.handle(list_of_buttons.index(button)))


    def handle(self,x):
        print x

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect the output to be an integer from 0 to 5 when I click each button but instead each button outputs the last index 5.

**Edit**

I tried the following

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda button = button: self.handle(list_of_buttons.index(button)))
```

But whenever I click a button I get

```
ValueError: False is not in list
```

So I tried changing the second loop to

```
for i in range(0,6):
        list_of_buttons[i].clicked.connect(lambda i=i: self.handle(i))
```

But even though the previous error no longer appears, it outputs *False* Whenever I click a button.

Comment: try `lambda button = button: self.handle(list_of_buttons.index(button))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I edited my post with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When button signals are emitted all lambdas you create see the same `__init__`'s namespace as it was after the last iteration of the loop and in which `button is self.pushButton_06`.
In your second variant the you are connecting to another signal: `clicked(checked)`; and PyQt ignores lambda argument's  default value and passes to it `False` which is printed out.

I'd solve this using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).
The loop in `__init__` might look like this:

```
for i, button in enumerate(list_of_buttons):
    slot = functools.partial(self.handle, i)
    button.clicked.connect(slot)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining what went wrong in both situations! Highly valuable, as I am still learning!

Comment: @NoahBishop To clarify: closures would work as in juanpa.arrivillaga suggestion unless PyQt weren't be so smart and not pick signal basing on slot signature.